# European Country/Region/Town data list

Tags: maps, street-address, country-codes

I want to have some combo boxes for selecting European regions and towns, where can I find some source data lists for it in English (but also with the local name if available)?

For example: France/Brittany/Arzon

Comment: that would highly interest me too

Comment: Did you ever find anywhere?

Comment: no, not really found anything yet and just typed the ones in that I needed

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/jim/carmen/ if you want to list subregions of a country.

E.g.

`spain = Country.named('Spain')`

`andalucia = spain.subregions.first`

`=> <#Carmen::Region name="Andalucía" type="autonomous community">`

Comment: thanks, bit framework dependent but could be exported to a file I guess